# Pandas custom ExtensionDtype ordering issues with reindex

Tags: python, pandas

I am implementing a custom ExtensionDtype and seeing that the order of the results becomes out of sync with the original index when using `reindex` operation or appending/concat on dataframes. I understand the result can be reordered but I expect the index/column names to be aligned with the data.

Here is my implementation.

```
@register_extension_dtype
class CategoryListWithHashFeatureDtype(ExtensionDtype):
    name = 'CategoryListWithHashFeature'
    type = CategoryListWithHashFeature
    kind = 'O'
    na_value = DEAL_NAN

    @classmethod
    def construct_array_type(cls):
        return CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray

    @classmethod
    def construct_from_string(cls, string):
        if string == cls.name:
            return cls()
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'Cannot construct a {cls} from {string}')
```

```
class CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray(ExtensionArray):

    def __init__(self, values: List[CategoryListWithHashFeature] = None):
        self._dtype = CategoryListWithHashFeatureDtype()
        self.raw_names: List[str] = []
        self.raw_values: List[Union[List[str], List[bytes]]] = []
        self.hash_names: List[str] = []
        self.hash_values: List[List[int]] = []

        if values:
            for feature in values:
                if isinstance(feature, CategoryListWithHashFeature):
                    self.raw_names.append(feature.name)
                    self.raw_values.append(feature.values)
                    self.hash_names.append(feature.hash_name)
                    self.hash_values.append(feature.hash_values)
                else:
                    self.raw_names.append(NAN_FEATURE_NAME)
                    self.raw_values.append([])
                    self.hash_names.append(NAN_FEATURE_NAME)
                    self.hash_values.append([])

    @classmethod
    def _from_values(cls,
                     raw_names: List[str],
                     raw_values: List[Union[List[str], List[bytes]]],
                     hash_names: List[str],
                     hash_values: List[List[int]]) -> CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray:
        inst = CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray()
        inst.raw_names = raw_names
        inst.raw_values = raw_values
        inst.hash_names = hash_names
        inst.hash_values = hash_values

        return inst

    @classmethod
    def _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype=None, copy=False):
        if isinstance(scalars, ndarray):
            scalars = list(scalars)
        return cls(scalars)

    @classmethod
    def _from_factorized(cls, values, original):
        return cls(values)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        try:
            if isinstance(index, int) or isinstance(index, np.int64):
                if len(self) == 0:
                    return CategoryListWithHashFeatureDtype.na_value

                return CategoryListWithHashFeature(
                    raw_name=self.raw_names[index],
                    raw_values=self.raw_values[index],
                    hash_name=self.hash_names[index],
                    hash_values=self.hash_values[index]
                )
            elif isinstance(index, slice):
                raw_names: List[str] = self.raw_names[index]
                return CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray([
                    CategoryListWithHashFeature(
                        raw_name=self.raw_names[idx],
                        raw_values=self.raw_values[idx],
                        hash_name=self.hash_names[idx],
                        hash_values=self.hash_values[idx])
                    for idx in range(len(raw_names))
                ])
            elif isinstance(index, ndarray):
                return CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray([
                    CategoryListWithHashFeature(
                        raw_name=self.raw_names[idx],
                        raw_values=self.raw_values[idx],
                        hash_name=self.hash_names[idx],
                        hash_values=self.hash_values[idx])
                    for idx in list(index)
                ])
            else:
                raise RuntimeError(f'Unsupported index type {str(type(index))}')
        except Exception:
            logging.exception(f'index: {index}. Val: {self.raw_names}')
            return self._dtype.na_value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.raw_names)

    @property
    def dtype(self):
        return self._dtype

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray):
            return False

        if len(self) != len(other):
            return False

        return all(self.__getitem__(idx) == other.__getitem__(idx) for idx in range(len(self)))

    def __hash__(self):
        h = 0
        for idx in range(len(self)):
            h += self.__getitem__(idx).__hash__()

        return h

    @property
    def nbytes(self):
        return sys.getsizeof(self.raw_names) + sys.getsizeof(self.raw_values) \
               + sys.getsizeof(self.hash_names) + sys.getsizeof(self.hash_values)

    def isna(self):
        missing_values = [val == CategoryListWithHashFeatureDtype.na_value or len(val) == 0 for val in self.raw_values]
        return np.array(missing_values)

    def take(self, indices, allow_fill=False, fill_value=None):
        # During reindex we get a -1 index if the item was not found in the original data
        data = [self.__getitem__(idx) for idx in indices if idx >= 0]
        if allow_fill and fill_value is None:
            fill_value = self._dtype.na_value

        result = pd.api.extensions.take(data, indices, fill_value=fill_value, allow_fill=allow_fill)
        return self._from_sequence(result)

    def copy(self, deep=False):
        copy = [self._copy_feature(idx) for idx in range(len(self.raw_names))]
        return type(self)(copy)

    def _copy_feature(self, idx: int) -> CategoryListWithHashFeature:
        return CategoryListWithHashFeature(
            raw_name=self.raw_names[idx],
            raw_values=self.raw_values[idx].copy(),
            hash_name=self.hash_names[idx],
            hash_values=self.hash_values[idx].copy()
        )

    @classmethod
    def _concat_same_type(cls, to_concat):
        raw_names: List[str] = []
        raw_values: List[Union[List[str], List[bytes]]] = []
        hash_names: List[str] = []
        hash_values: List[List[int]] = []

        for feature_array in to_concat:  # type: CategoryListWithHashFeatureArray
            raw_names.extend(feature_array.raw_names)
            raw_values.extend(feature_array.raw_values)
            hash_names.extend(feature_array.hash_names)
            hash_values.extend(feature_array.hash_values)

        return cls._from_values(raw_names=raw_names,
                                raw_values=raw_values,
                                hash_names=hash_names,
                                hash_values=hash_values)
```

Tests:

```
category_list_features = [
    CategoryListWithHashFeature('size2', ['s', 'm'], 'size2_hash', [2]),
    CategoryListWithHashFeature('color', ['R'], 'color_hash', [1])
]

s1 = Series({f.name: f for f in category_list_features}, dtype='CategoryListWithHashFeature')
s2 = s1.reindex(index=['color', 'size', 'size2'])

print(s2)

color    size2: ['s', 'm'] / Hashed size2: [2]
size            :NAN_F: [] / Hashed :NAN_F: []
size2    color: ['R'] / Hashed color_hash: [1]
dtype: CategoryListWithHashFeature
```

My initial guess was there was something incorrect about my handling of the negative indices in the take method so I added the negative index check. Index values I get in my take method: [1, -1, 0] ==> the -1 corresponds to the missing `size` index/value in the series. I know this incorrect because the take function can actually get legit negative index and i need to support it. If I remove the negative index check I get the color value duplicated:

```
color    color: ['R'] / Hashed color_hash: [1]
size            :NAN_F: [] / Hashed :NAN_F: []
size2    color: ['R'] / Hashed color_hash: [1]
dtype: CategoryListWithHashFeature
```

I did some debugging and this seems to happen in the pandas.algorithms.take_nd function:
Relevant snippet:

```
func = _get_take_nd_function(
        arr.ndim, arr.dtype, out.dtype, axis=axis, mask_info=mask_info
    )
    func(arr, indexer, out, fill_value)
```

I am using pandas version 1.2.1
I would appreciate some help on this. Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was probably a silly question. If I have my own take method, I don't need to call `pd.api.extensions.take` again. I can just return my calculated results.

I would still like to know the reason for the internal take returning the unexpected result.